# hacer que expresión regular reciba una variable

Tags: javascript, regex

tengo la siguiente expresión regular:

```
  var exp = 'plata|gol'
  if (/(\W|^)(gol)(\W|$)/.test(dataVal)) {
   console.log("bien")

  } else {
   console.log("paila")
  }
```

necesito que donde está la palabra gol reciba exp como validador he intentado con backticks, pero no funciono agradezco la ayuda

Comment: ya intentaste con le constructor y crear un objeto?

Comment: dame un ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

Usando el objeto RegExp, puedes "convertir" un string a regexp, y hacer lo que estás necesitando:

```
const exp = 'plata|gol';
const re = new RegExp('(\W|^)('+exp+')(\W|$)');
let dataVal = 'gol';

if (re.test(dataVal)) {
    console.log("bien");
}else{
    console.log("paila");
}
```

Puedes encontrar más información en: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions